How to send a response message to particular employee
I am trying to create a human approval process using AWS step function. In this process after executing a State machine manager get a mail from employee side with links for approval or rejection of their promotion request. I want that whenever manager click on any one of the link employee get an appropriate mail regarding their request status.
How can I implement it
I want to send a response mail to the particular employee when manager click on any of the link

Start by providing what you have tried and where you run into issues. If you want somebody to write it for you, hire someone.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
